# Automatically forget wi-fi settings on log out - Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I am setting up a shared laptop and I need the wifi settings to be forgotten on a log out - I can't see a way of doing this in Windows 10. Anyone found anything, or is a batch file the way to go?
thanks

Comment: `netsh wlan delete profile`

Comment: Thanks David. I need to remove all profiles automatically on log out, and I need this to happen for all created profiles. Getting users to run a CMD prompt is not going to happen

Comment: [How to schedule a task to run when shutting down windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101647) covers logoff as well.

Comment: `netsh wlan show profiles` and loop with a `for` command.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for this. Writing batch scripts is not what I do routinely: I am aware of what they are and a little of how to use them, but I am unfamiliar with the syntax and language. I write a lot of VBA within Access, but am otherwise ignorant. I will try to write something and post it up for any comment for which I would be grateful.